# mock with predicate without It.isany

Tags: c#, asp.net, moq

I need one help to solve my mock related question in .net, I have one function with below code.

```
Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> includes = null);
```

Where we have a T as class, now I want to use the below code for the mocking.

```
var predict = PredicateBuilder.True<cls1>();
if (DropdownRequestVM?.AllParent == false)
{
   predict = predict.And(x => x.Parentid == DropdownRequestVM.ParentID);
}
  else
{
   predict = predict.And(x => x.Parentid == null);
}

var returneddata = data.AsQueryable().Where(predict).ToList();

this.mockservice
 .Setup(repo => repo.Repository
 .GetAllAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func< cls1, bool>>>(),
 It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable< cls1>, IOrderedQueryable< cls1>>>(),
               It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable< cls1>, IQueryable< cls1>>>()))
.Returns(Task.FromResult<ICollection< cls1>>(returneddata));
```

Now my query is. I do not want to use the It.isany, as its allow all the expression, so that I have passed predict, but even I have setup the methods. Its returning the null. I have setup the method below way.

```
this.mockservice
 .Setup(repo => repo.Repository
 .GetAllAsync(predict,
 It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable< cls1>, IOrderedQueryable< cls1>>>(),
               It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable< cls1>, IQueryable< cls1>>>()))
.Returns(Task.FromResult<ICollection< cls1>>(returneddata));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like, not 100% sure about the syntax

```
this.mockservice
 .Setup(repo => repo.Repository
 .GetAllAsync(It.Is<Expression<Func<cls1,bool>>>(x => LambdaCompare.Eq(x,predict)),It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<cls1>, IOrderedQueryable<cls1>>>(),It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<cls1>, IQueryable<cls1>>>()))
.Returns(Task.FromResult<ICollection< cls1>>(returneddata));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, finally the issue is resolved. we have to use  Neleus.LambdaCompare.Lambda.Eq(x,predict)